# file_put_contents from multiple requests into specific format PHP

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I want to put content from 2 or more requests into a file that will be formatted as:

```
customer | invoice
```

Below I managed to get both request to be posted, but how do I get them to be posted in the below format:

```
Customer1 | Invoice1  
Customer2 | Invoice2    ..etc
```

**PHP Code :**

```
file_put_contents('/root/service_Logs/service.log',"
                             {$this->request->customer}\n",FILE_APPEND); 
file_put_contents('/root/service_Logs/service.log',
                             "{$this->‌​request->invoice}\n‌​",FILE_APPEND);
```

Edit: Still not apple to get them in that format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about it:

```
$file = '/root/service_Logs/service.log';
$text = sprintf('%s | %s', $this->request->customer, $this->request->invoice);
file_put_contents($file, $text . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

I'm using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) because it allows me to specify the *format* of a string *separately from the data* to that format.

You could also use interpolation, but that's more cluttered in my opinion:

```
$text = "{$this->request->customer} | {$this->request->invoice}";
```

But, whatever you do, strive to keep your variables declaration separate from the logic of using those variables. When you wrapped everything up into a single call, it gets lengthy and messy and hard to maintain. Even for throw away lines like logging statements, it's a bad habit to have.

Comment: I am trying to add a time stamp for each entry . I used the below code: $text = sprintf( date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - " '%s | %s', $this->request->customer, $this->request->invoice); but no luck with the output. what did i do wrong?

Comment: `$text = sprintf('%s %s | %s', date(...), ...);`